# Dynamic visibility layer markers in LeafletJS

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to render 5 sets of data on a map, one at a time, selectable by the user.

I'm using layers to store each set and I can switch between them - works well.

I want to be able to filter each set based on user input. I was using `L.layerGroup` but tried reformatting my data at load time to GeoJSON so I could use the built in filter feature. That only seems to work if I remove the layers and re-add each marker.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/callum/5sunB/

For 1000 points, on my system it takes about 200ms which is too slow.

Is there a way to only show/hide the markers already in a layer based on a filter function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not really.  You can save your markers and then it's faster to just add them to the map than it is to re-create them and then add them.

For example,

```
var markers = new Array();
...
// create a marker using some unique id and save it to the markers array
var i = feature.properties.id;
markers[i] = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        ....
        });
return markers[i];
```

Then when you filter (on click or other event), clear the marker layer and re-add the (saved) markers that match:

```
if (map.hasLayer(marker_layer)) {
    map.removeLayer(marker_layer);
}
marker_layer = new L.featureGroup();
// filter criteria here
for (var i = 0; i < src_data.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = src_data.features[i];
    if (feature.properties.hits >= n1 && feature.properties.hits <= n2) {
      marker_layer.addLayer(markers[i]);
    }
}
marker_layer.addTo(map);
```

I updated your JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sunB/5/ so you can compare re-creating the filtered markers vs just re-adding them.

Comment: Shame but that approach is definitely faster kielni - thank you.

My slider goes from 0 - 100 in steps of 1. I wondered if I could make a layer for each the 100 discrete 'states' and show/hide them based on the slider values.  Sounds a bit unwieldy - especially if I ever want more granularity.

Comment: I woulg go for the 100 layers approach. In my similar case I can't use layers as I have multiple filter conditions, leaving with more than 1,000,000 discrete states.